# windows phone 8 pivot

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

Recently I am busy doing a project about calendar. The teacher told me that a user may have many calendars. So I want to use pivot to show them.

However, as the user can choose how many and which calendar to show in the app, I can not get exactly the number and just depend on the program to remember.

I want to ask how to achieve the task. And I also want to know if there are too many calendars to show, how to make the pivot fast. Maybe a pivot item has an limitation. Could anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Consider including some code you have tried or phrasing the question much more specifically as it will be more likely to get a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a design perspective and given the unknown number of calendars, I don't think a Pivot is what you should use. If you take a look at the [design guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/design/hh202919%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), you'll note:

> Apps should minimize the number of pivot pages (four pages or fewer).
>   Users can become lost if they jump from pivot page to pivot page. Use
>   Pivot controls sparingly and limit the use of pivot pages to scenarios
>   where it’s appropriate for the experience.

and

> The Pivot control should be used only to display items or data of
>   similar type (for example, filtered views of the same data).

The latter doesn't preclude what you are doing, but most of the apps that I've seen use pivots to provide alternate views of the same data versus the same view of different data (as you'd be doing).

I think a simple list of the available calendars that navigates to a second page for the calendar (with binding to your specific calendar's view model) would be easier and more intuitive.

Comment: thanks, but I think the calendar maybe almost the same. for example, the difference among the normal calendar, the birthday calendar and my friend's birthday calendar can just be some day being highlighted. I hope you can give some more detailed advice. Thanks very much.

Comment: IMO, the determining factor should be user experience.  With three calendars navigating a pivot is ok, with ten, it's frustrating.  If you have essentially one data set and the calendars are indeed different views, then you may be able to data bind off of one model, which would reduce/eliminate concerns about speed. I'm not sure we can provide a lot more detail - probably time to prototype and see if the experience works.